# Inconsistency in number of parameters in base and child methods signatures

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, overriding, method-signature

I have a `Base` class with certain method and w/o any parameters:

```
class Base():

    def pretty_method(self):
        print('Hi!')
```

And there are several subclasses and they need additional proceeding in `pretty_method` with new parameter `x`.

```
class A(Base):

    def pretty_method(self, x):
        super().pretty_method()
        print('X in A is {}'.format(x))

class B(Base):

    def pretty_method(self, x):
        super().pretty_method()
        print('X in B is {}'.format(x))
```

So in that case I have inconsistency in class methods signature.

In other hand I could deal with unused `x` parameter in base class:

```
class Base():

    def pretty_method(self, x=None):
        print('Hi!')
```

That is kinda useless, but keeps signatures in consistency.
What is more preferable approach?

Comment: There is no need to consistency in this case. You are overriding the method so why it should have same signature as the base class's method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding new attributes / methods in a derived class is fine, removing them isn't because it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Consider: all classes in (modern) Python derive from `object`, and they'd be useless if they didn't add new attributes &/or methods. So it's perfectly normal to add new args to a derived class's `__init__` method.

Of course, if you expect the majority of the derived classes to use the `x` argument, then it's perfectly fine to add it to the base class too, even though the base class itself doesn't use it.

On a related note, it's a common practice to add methods to a base class that the base class itself doesn't use but which the derived classes are expected to override. In such cases, it's normal for the base method to raise `NotImplemented`. You don't *need* to supply such methods in the base class, but it does make the error message more informative in case someone forgets to supply the method in their derived class.